# How can I show $(X_{1} / r_{1}) / (X_{2} / r_{2})$ and $(X_{3} / r_{3}) / ( (X_{1} + X_{2}) / (r_{1} + r_{2}) ) )$ are independent?

Tags: self-study, chi-squared-test, independence, f-distribution

In the book  by Hogg and Craig 6th edition,

there is a problem numbered 3.6.14. saying that

If  $X_{1}$, $X_{2}$, and $X_{3}$ are three independent chi-squre variables with degrees of freedom $r_{1}$, $r_{2}$, $r_{3}$ respectively, show that $X_{1} / r_{1}) / (X_{2} / r_{2})$ and $(X_{3} / r_{3}) / ( (X_{1} + X_{2}) / (r_{1} + r_{2}) ) )$ are independent.

Actually, it is a part (b) of 3.6.14., but from (a), we know that $X_{1}/X_{2}$ and $X_{1}+X_{2}$ are independent. Of course, we can solve (b) by tedious calculations, but I want to know the neat solution. But even if I tried, I cannot know the solution.

I guess that if there are three random variables $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ s.t. $X$ and $Y$ are independent, and $X$ and $Z$ are independent, then for any functions $f$ and $g$, $f(X)$ and $g(Y,Z)$ are independent. If this is true, then the question above would be obvious fact.
But I don't know whether the statement is true or not.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Since this is explicitly a standard textbook type problem I've taken the liberty of adding the `self-study` [tag](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).